# Scan and register dependencies for all class implementing an interface in an application

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I've got the code below from a sample app which uses structure map.

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<IAppointmentRepository>();
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<SchedulingContext>();
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<ScheduleRepository>();
        scan.AssemblyContainingType<CrudContext>();
        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(ClientPatientManagement.Core.Interfaces.IRepository<>));
        scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));
    });
};
```

I want to do the same thing in my own solution using autofac, especially the line that reads

```
scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));
```

I don't know if this does the same thing with the above code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(p => p.IsClass)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing` method of StructureMap connects implementations to open generic types.

Hence:

```
scan.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));
```

will register all implementations that close the open generic type IHandle<>

The equivalent in **AutoFac** would be:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
   .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IHandle<>))
   .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

See the following links for more information

1. [AutoFac Scanning](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Scanning)
2. [AutoFac Open Generics](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Open-Generics)